# Android up button doesn't open parent activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm developing an app using the Android Support Library to implement ActionBar on old devices, but I'm  encountering a problem.
The problem is that when I press the [Up button](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) the activity doesn't start the *parent activity,* but the activity that started the current one.
The problem occurs on Android 4.2.2 KitKat *but not* on Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread.

```
<activity android:name=".innerPackage.SecondaryActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:parentActivityName="com.dev.myapp.OtherActivity">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
               android:value="com.dev.myapp.OtherActivity"/>
</activity>
```

The activities are:

- com.dev.myapp.MainActivity.java;
- com.dev.myapp.innerpackage.SecondaryActivity.java;
- com.dev.myapp.OtherActivity.java.

The sequence is: MainActivity -> *open* SecondaryActivity -> *press Up button* -> MainActivity (but it should start OtherActivity).

Comment: The link seems to be wrong. 404 here.

Comment: Did u add `android:parentActivityName=""` in your Manifest? Post your manifest file..

Comment: Now the link is correct.

Comment: Yes, the parent activity is declared in manifest...

Comment: Post your manifest and any where else you coded it. We can't help if we don't see any code ;-)

Comment: I've added the manifest and other details.